# cambio de valores automático JQuery

Tags: jquery

estoy trabajando en una vista previa de en donde puedes cambiar los valores y se muestran en automático solo que no sé por qué razón , al usar una función con jQuery esta cambia todos los valores de los di cuando solo se especifica en la función cual se cambia, aquí el ejemplo:

```
// estos son lo input que tendrán el nuevo valor:
<div class="input-group mb-3">
<span class="input-group-text" style="background-color: #e047ab ;" id="basic-addon1">Titulo</span>
<input type="text" name="Titulo" id="Tituloinput" class="form-control mr-3">
</div>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
<span class="input-group-text" style="background-color: #5e50d8 ;" id="basic-addon1">Parrafo 1</span>
<input type="text" name="Parrafo1" id="ParrafoInput1" class="form-control mr-3">
</div>

// Estos son los div a cambiar :
<div id="Titulo" style="background-color: #e047ab ;" style="font-size: 3em;">Titulo</div>
<div id="Parrafo1" style="background-color: #5e50d8 ;">Parrafo1</div>
```

```
       //CAMBIAR TITULO 
       $(".FormularioTicket ").bind("change","div#Tituloinput",function(){
           Parrafo1()
       });

       function Parrafo1(){
           var parrafo1 = document.getElementById('Tituloinput').value;
           document.getElementById('Titulo').innerHTML=parrafo1;   
       }
       //CAMBIAR TITULO 

       //CAMBIAR PARRAFO1 
       $(".FormularioTicket").bind("change", "div#ParrafoInput1",function(){
           Parrafo2()
       });

       function Parrafo2(){
           var parrafo2 = document.getElementById('ParrafoInput1').value;
           document.getElementById('Parrafo1').innerHTML=parrafo2;
       }
```

pienso que tiene que ver algo la función bind debería usar una nueva versión de jQuery para solucionar esto o estoy haciendo algo mal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se que versión usas de jQuery, pero creo que el método `change()` está en todas ellas, y lo puedes aprovechar para hacerlo de este modo (he cambiado todas las funciones javascript puras por métodos de jquery, pues o bien usas unas o bien otras, pero mezclarlas no es buena idea y no facilita su lectura):

```
$(".FormularioTicket ").change(function() {
  inputModificado = $(event.target)
  switch (inputModificado.attr('id')) {
    case "Tituloinput":
      $('#Titulo').html(inputModificado.val());
      break;
    case "ParrafoInput1":
      $('#Parrafo1').html(inputModificado.val());
      break;
  }
});
```

Es decir, en una sola captura del evento discriminamos cual es el `id` que lo lanza mediante el atributo `id` del elemento representado por `$(event.target)`, que es el que lanza el evento en primera instancia antes de ir escalándolo por la jerarquía y que termina llegando al elemento con la clase `FormularioTicket` que lo contiene.

Luego, mediante un `switch`, identificamos su `id` y evaluamos si realizamos una acción u otra mediante sus claúsulas `case`. Y como ya tenemos el elemento asignado a [event.target](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) no hace falta hacerlo con un `getElementById()` ni usar más funciones, pues lo ponemos todo en la misma claúsula `case` y nos ahorramos algo de código.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo completo funcional:

```js
$(".FormularioTicket ").change(function() {
  inputModificado = $(event.target)
  switch (inputModificado.attr('id')) {
    case "Tituloinput":
      $('#Titulo').html(inputModificado.val());
      break;
    case "ParrafoInput1":
      $('#Parrafo1').html(inputModificado.val());
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="FormularioTicket">
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <span class="input-group-text" style="background-color: #e047ab ;" id="basic-addon1">Titulo</span>
    <input type="text" name="Titulo" id="Tituloinput" class="form-control mr-3">
  </div>

  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <span class="input-group-text" style="background-color: #5e50d8 ;" id="basic-addon2">Parrafo 1</span>
    <input type="text" name="Parrafo1" id="ParrafoInput1" class="form-control mr-3">
  </div>
  <div id="Titulo" style="background-color: #e047ab ; font-size: 3em;">Titulo</div>
  <div id="Parrafo1" style="background-color: #5e50d8 ;">Parrafo1</div>
</form>
```